Flask Sessions are expiring before set expiration time
My flask sessions are expiring before the set expiration time i.e in my case 24 hours. I have gone through flask documentation and enable permanent session life time and session permanent parameters but these dont seem to work. My application is hosted on AWS with nginx as reverse proxy server and gunicorn as my backend server.
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = os.getenv('SESSION_TYPE')
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(hours=24)

cookie set to 24 hours and i can check it from application tab on browser but upon certain time of inactivity / closing of browser it asks to login not refresh. Indicatinng google id set in session dict is disappearing.
I have exhausted my ways in trying to fix this. Any implementations on how fix and debug above issue is highly appreciated.

What is the value of os.getenv('SESSION_TYPE')

May sound dumb,  but you did remember to import timedelta from datetime? Also, have you tried setting the delta to "days=1" instead of hours=24?

session type is filesystem. timedelta is imported else it will thow an error. My application is up an running  and yes i have tried using days =1 as well.Nothing worked.
